# Why do we run Dijkstra's algorithm only V times in Johnson's algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, dijkstra

After running Bellman-Ford, and reweighing the graph, we can get positive edges. But to find the shortest path between every all pairs, doesn't this mean we have to run Dijkstra's V^2 times? Because for V vertices, V choose 2 = V(V-1)/2! so O(V^2) time. Why is it only that we run Dijkstra's V times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any two points, each time we run Bellman-Ford we correctly extend our understanding of the shortest path by at least one edge.  And then stop improving.

The longest possible shortest path visits every vertex in the graph once.  That path has `V` vertices and `V-1` edges.  Therefore once we've run `V-1` times we must have found every possible shortest path.